# How can I edit Identity pages (register, login...) with asp.net Core version 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, version

I'm trying to change the Login and Register pages with the version 2.1 of Core. This version doesn't show the pages like this:
[image]

Instead, the Pages folder only has one item:

[image]

I've seen may tutorial, and to edit these pages I need to add the IdentityScaffolder to my project. However, everytime I try doing this I get this error:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening. Is there any way I can edit the Login and Register pages? Can I create new ones?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, go to Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager >Package Manager Setting > General > Clear All Nuget Cache(s).

For more details, you may refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44727789/11965297).